# How to get the checked checkboxes of a particular ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a dynamic ul and trying to get the checked boxes of a particular ul only.

```js
$(document).on("click", "input:checkbox[name=filter]:checked", function() {
  var flags = Array();
  $("input:checkbox[name=filter]:checked").each(function() {
    flags.push($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="form">Form</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="anonymise">Anonymise</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="priority">Priority</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="question">Question</li>
</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="form">Form</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="anonymise">Anonymise</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="priority">Priority</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="question">Question</li>
</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="form">Form</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="anonymise">Anonymise</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="priority">Priority</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="question">Question</li>
</ul>
```

all the three **UL** are identical, in this case how can i get the the all the checkboxes of a particular ul only.

this gives me all the selected checkboxes from all uls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want only the ul containing that clicked element. Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "input:checkbox[name=filter]:checked", function(){
    var flags = Array();
    $("input:checkbox[name=filter]:checked", $(this).parents("ul").first()).each(function(){
        flags.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(flags);
});
```

The inner `each` function has a `$(this).parents("ul").first()` scope identifier before it. This will filter the inputs by the container of the clicked input.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you need to get the `closest()` `ul` element, then `find()` all the checkboxes within that `ul` before looping over them to build the array. Also note that you can simplify the loop by using `map()` instead. Try this:

```js
$(document).on("click", "input:checkbox[name=filter]:checked", function() {
  var flags = $(this).closest('ul').find("input:checkbox[name=filter]:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  console.log(flags);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="form">Form</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="anonymise">Anonymise</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="priority">Priority</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="question">Question</li>
</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="form">Form</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="anonymise">Anonymise</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="priority">Priority</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="question">Question</li>
</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="form">Form</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="anonymise">Anonymise</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="priority">Priority</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="question">Question</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare flags variable outside the function so that each selected checkbox value can be pushed to the array.

```js
var flags = Array();
$(document).on("click", "input:checkbox[name=filter]:checked", function() {
  flags.push($(this).val());
  console.log(flags);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="form">Form</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="anonymise">Anonymise</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="priority">Priority</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="question">Question</li>
</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="form">Form</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="anonymise">Anonymise</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="priority">Priority</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="question">Question</li>
</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="form">Form</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="anonymise">Anonymise</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="priority">Priority</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="question">Question</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
var flags;
$("input[name=filter]").on("click",function(){
    var ul = $(this).parent().parent();
    flags = ul.find("input:checked").map(function(){return this.value});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use delegated event handler, you can use the delegateTarget property of the event object:

> event.delegateTarget
>
> The element where the currently-called jQuery event handler was attached.

You can then use this delegateTarget to restrict your search of checkboxes, using find.

Example:

```js
$("ul.dropdown-list").on("click", "input:checkbox[name=filter]:checked", function(e) {
    //console.log(e.target); /* input:checked */
    //console.log(e.delegateTarget); /* ul.dropdown-list */
    var checkedBoxes = $(e.delegateTarget).find("input:checkbox[name=filter]:checked");
    var selections = checkedBoxes.map((id, inp) => inp.value);
    console.log(selections.get());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="form">Form</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="anonymise">Anonymise</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="priority">Priority</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="question">Question</li>
</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="form">Form</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="anonymise">Anonymise</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="priority">Priority</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="question">Question</li>
</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="form">Form</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="anonymise">Anonymise</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="priority">Priority</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="question">Question</li>
</ul>
```